# My login page keeps returning "incorrect login" even when I enter correct login

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote a simple login page that is connected to a mySQL database.  **But even when I try to put in the correct login information, it still returns the "Incorrect username or password" error.**  I can't figure out if there is something wrong with my code itself, or my database.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My database looks like this:  https://gyazo.com/da06e276d981a35a3e2f01f5ec17f27b

I currently have 2 entries in that database for testing: https://gyazo.com/04a52dde61e77e0cbc2f90b78b3f40a9

My index.php code is as follows

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Include Login Script
if ((isset($_SESSION['username']) != '')) 
{
header('Location: home.php');
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Login Form with Session</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>PHP Login Form with Session</h1>
<div class="loginBox">
<h3>Login Form</h3>
<br><br>
<form method="post" action="">
<label>Username:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /><br><br>
<label>Password:</label><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />  <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form>
<div class="error"><?php echo $error;?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My login.php code is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connection.php"); //Establishing connection with our database

$error = ""; //Variable for storing our errors.
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
{
$error = "Both fields are required.";
}else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

//Check username and password from database
$sql="SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//If username and password exist in our database then create a session.
//Otherwise echo error.

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
$_SESSION['username'] = $login_user; // Initializing Session
header("location: home.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}else
{
$error = "Incorrect username or password.";
}

}
}

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")`

Comment: As the above comments mention, this code is very very susceptible to SQL injection. Look into PDO parameterized queries. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo is a great primer.

Comment: Also, a book entitled "Modern PHP" by O'Reilly goes through a modern, secure, way to create a login page. I highly recommend purchasing and reading it, if you are building an app that will be available on the internet. As is, this code is so vulnerable to attack it makes me need a beer :) I have written code like this in the past, don't worry about it, but do take the time to learn the proper ways.

Comment: The final recommendation I will make is Phpstorm IDE. With it, and XDebug, you can step through your code line by line and inspect the values of variables. An easy way to get started with XDebug debugging is XAMPP. That said, a better way than XAMPP is using a Vagrant Virtual Machine and/or Docker.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments but I'm not really interested in building a super fancy set-up.  I'm just a few hours into PHP and SQL and I just want to figure out why my code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

1- Saving in plain text is a NO.
2- As far as i can see you are comparing a plain text password with its md5.
You have also defined the same variable more than once, with different values, sth ive never seen before.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I removed the part of my code that converts the password to md5.  Could you please elaborate on what variables I've defined more than once?

Comment: You edited that, either way, try using require_once instead of include.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see where $login_user is assigned a value in your code in login.php page.
Try

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Also replace this with what you have at the top of your index.php page.

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Include Login Script
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header('Location: home.php');
}
else{}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I made all the changes you recommended but was still unable to successfully login.  Is there anything else you could suggest?

Answer (score 0):

First of since you have your login script on another file in your project directory, shouldn't you specify the location to the script on your login form? Just like this

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
      <label>Username:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /><br><br>
      <label>Password:</label><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />  <br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /> 
    </form>
```